# .net maui Listview ItemSelected not selected when inner elements focused

Tags: maui

I have a `ListView` with one button and one entry on it's `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListView
    x:Name="LstMedios"
    Grid.Row="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MediosDePago}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding MedioPagoSeleccionado,Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="2*,*" >
                    <Button 
                        Text="My button" 
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5,5" />
                    <Entry 
                        Text="{Binding NumValor,StringFormat='{0:c}'}" 
                        Keyboard="Numeric" 
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Margin="0,5,5,5">
                    </Entry>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I expect when my Entry is focused then my listview `SelectedItem` must be set, but it remains null.

What is the proper way to force my listview to automatically set `SelectedItem` when any of its controls on `ItemTemplate` is focused?

[Full sample](https://github.com/jupagose/maui-listview-bug)

Comment: What do you mean Entry is focused then listview SelectedItem must be set, but it remains null? Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, Here is the repro sample  https://github.com/jupagose/maui-listview-bug

Comment: Thanks for the update, you can see my solution below!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, what you expect is that when directly hitting on the `Button` or the `Entry`(get focused), the `SelectedItem` below should be triggered.

```
public TestItem SelectedItem
{
    get => _SelectedItem;
    set => SetProperty(ref _SelectedItem, value);
}
```

However, the `SelectedItem` will only be set if clicking on the frame border or outside of it and the background color of the selected item will be `Orange`. And this potential issue happens both in `ListView` and `CollectionView`.

In conclusion, this potential issue is related or similar to [CollectionView's SelectionChanged method cannot be triggered when tapping the item directly #9567](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9567). You can try [this workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9567#issuecomment-1245953748) provided by PhoenixWyllow or follow up on it. Besides, you can also raise a [new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) on Github if you are willing to.

**Update:**

For now, Juan implemented a transparent button over the Entry element this way can get access to `selected item` posting it from CommandParameter.

Comment: I'm really enjoing MAUI but is so buggy, for now I implemented a transparent button over My Entry element this way I get access to selected item posting it from CommandParameter.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I added your temporary solution to the answer. You can accept it as answer as it will help others who have similar issue!